# Print.CSS forcing element to appear on last page

Tags: html, css

I have done some research trying to figure this issue out but am unable to find anything that will help me.

This may seem sloppy, so I will try my best to explain.

On my webpage, I have a bunch of tables, with graphs that represent the same data as the table but it gives the user a visual of the data.

I have created a Print.CSS style sheet and I don't know how to make all of the graphs appear on the last pages to be printed.  Is there a way to do that?

Here is more of a visual of what I am currently dealing with, in respect to printing:

```
table1
graph1

table2
graph2

table3
graph3
```

What I am looking for, to be printed, is this:

```
table1 // page 1

table2 // page 2

table3 // page 3

graph1 // page 4

graph2 // page 5

graph3 // page 6
```

I have tried:

```
#graph1, #graph2, #graph3{
    page-break-before: always; // to put the graphs on their own page
}
```

But this just puts the table on its own page then the corresponding graph on the next, and so on and so on.

How do I put all of the tables first, then graph 1 on the page after the last table, then graph 2 on the page after graph 1, etc?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure if this will work with printing but you could try using `display:flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/fhjvxftt/1/

Comment: @Pete I just tried that but it did not work. everything stayed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you, where you put the markup in print order and use `flex` to alter the screen order.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0) {
  
  .gph {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .nr1 {
    order:1;
  }
  .nr2 {
    order:2;
  }
  .nr3 {
    order:3;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tbl nr1">table 1</div>
  <div class="tbl nr2">table 2</div>
  <div class="tbl nr3">table 3</div>
  
  <div class="gph nr1">graph 1</div>
  <div class="gph nr2">graph 2</div>
  <div class="gph nr3">graph 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to use this because I was able to find a different solution before you posted but thank you for the answer.  It is appreciated none the less.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just got it to work.  My graphs and tables are all partial views.. and I am using those partial views in my Main view.  In all of my partial views, my graphs are `<img>`'s, so this is what I did in each of my partial views:

```
<img class="print-hide" src='@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")' /> // print-hide is on my Print.CSS with display: none
```

that way when I print, it hides the img (graph) after the table.. and then on my Main view I created a section after all of the tables calling the same images:

```
<section>
    //graph1 
    //graph2
    //etc
</section>
```

So when I print now, it hides the graphs in the partial views but they are in my main view, after all of the tables.